# Cannot get stored document from mongodb using spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have document with  `"_id" : ObjectId("5449567cdf97f277c50d1ce2")` but I am getting `null` when trying to get it by `id` using `findOne`. How to solve it?

**main**

```
public class MongoDBJDBC {
    public static void main( String args[] ){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        ProductService productService = context.getBean(ProductService.class);
        Product product = productService.get("5449567cdf97f277c50d1ce2"); // null here
        }
}
```

**service**

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;
    @Autowired
    private ProductPropertiesDao productPropertiesDao;

    public void add(Product product) {
        productDao.save(product);
    }

    public void update(Product product) {
        productDao.save(product);
    }

    public Product get(String id) {
        return productDao.get(id);
    }
```

**dao**

```
    @Repository
    public class ProductDao  {

        @Autowired
        private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
 public Product get(String id) {
        return mongoOperations.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId(id))), Product.class);
    }
}
```

**entity**

```
@Document(collection = Product.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    public Product() {
    }

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "product";

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String name;
   }
```

**document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5449567cdf97f277c50d1ce2"),
    "name" : "product"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB adds underline prefix before ID field, so you should use `Criteria.where("_id").` instead of just `id`.

Comment: Seems like it solves problem but I get right after `org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type org.bson.types.ObjectId to type int`. What might it be?

Comment: Try to use `.is(id))` instead of `new ObjectId(id)`